# How to split string, apply function to every part and rejoin back without loops in .NET?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to perform these actions inside single evaluation, if possible:

1. split the string `input` into parts according to separator `separator`
2. apply function `fnc(String)  -> String` to every part
3. rejoin parts back to string `result` using the same separator `separator`

That's all.

The best I could figure out was (this is in VB)

```
result = input.Split(separator).Aggregate(String.Empty,
            Function(result, part) _
                result & If(result = String.Empty, String.Empty, separator) &
                fnc(part))
```

As you can see, this is ugly because

- `Aggregate()` needs initialization in 1st parameter (if `Aggregate()` is used without first parameter, it doesn't call `fnc()` for 1st element of array)
- this approach forces `if()` usage, otherwise `separator` is added to start of result

I experimented using `Select()` and `SelectMany()` on array created through `Split()`, but then when I apply `String.Join()` on their result, I'm getting cast error(!) during the runtime (build works OK) and I do not exactly understand why.

Here is the effective form which crashes during runtime:

```
result = String.Join(separator, input.Split(separator).SelectMany(Function(part) fnc(part)))
```

With Exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
'd__14`2[System.String,System.Char]' to type 'System.String[]'.
```

Could you please suggest better approach for this evaluation? If can be that `Select()` and `SelectMany()` made working with `String.Join()`... or is there some other effective way?

Feel free to respond in VB or C#.

**EDIT:** this is about HOW this can be done, not how easily readable such a code might be for someone. [Lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) used also here look alien to many programmers. We all know how classic approach to this problem looks like - `foreach` with helper variables are around...

Comment: Whats wrong with multiple code lines? If you're obssesed too much with number of lines reduction you will get inneficient code, which will be bad code although it has less lines.

Comment: Not to mention readability. Compressed code is difficult code. Whitespace is good. Semicolons are good. Non-truncated variable names are good.

Comment: I believe that for this simple scenario the parts are already there (in libraries), they need to be correctly put together. And this is more frequent and more general case than shown on the above string example so if would be beneficial to have reference to such an approach somewhere.

Comment: result = String.Join(separator, s.Split(New Char() {separator(0)}).Select(Function(t) Fnc(t)))

Comment: @SysDragon excuse me, but your post is a bit off-topic. Of course I know approach you suggest but I was interested in another approach this time... I find StackOverflow as place to ask questions which can help not only me but to community. 
I'm not flagging your post also for benefit of others to see how not to react.

Comment: @miroxlav Relax! Why do you get defensive? Im just trying to give you and advice, and not flagging or downvoting your post. Im sure your comment is a better example of how not to react.

Comment: @SysDragon Finally I've come to simple, clean and effective working solution. Happy coding! Believe me, sometimes I have enough of writing loops for obvious things which can be done better and shorter. Of course, for clearer code, the disucssed mechanism can be encapsulated in single function.

Comment: OP adds my answer to the question and uses it in his own answer. Is now waiting for his answer to be flaggable. Community cancer, right here.

Comment: @Gusdor Oh Gusdor... if you check version of my question which appeared shortly after original posting, `String.Join` was already in the Question long before you posted your Answer. If you can review your answer and tell me WHAT new it brought in... I think nothing, all was included in the question before you wrote answer. I did not want to be rude so I did not tell you that you did NOT read entire question :( Now I'm telling you. You can verify this in version history. Peace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After additional thinking and trying I've found out that a **simple solution** really exists:

```
result = String.Join(separator,
                     input.Split(separator).Select(
                     Function(part) fnc(part)).ToArray())
```

Clean and effective!

So `Select()` approach mentioned in the question was way to working result. **Adding `ToArray()` to its result did the trick**.

Thank you for all your help effort!

Comment: May you have to debug that statement often, so that someone else doesn't have to figure out what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: @StingyJack that statement actually has no 'moving parts' which might need debugging except of the function `fnc()`. Inner code of `fnc()` remains fully available to debugging as it was in 'standard' coding approach.

Comment: You can mark your answer as the answer if it solved the problem to your satisfaction.

Comment: @AndrewMorton StackOverflow lets me mark my own post as the answer no sooner than 2 days from posting. In the meantime, anyone who likes it can vote.

Answer (score 0):

Try [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)

> Concatenates all the elements of a string array, using the specified
>   separator between each element.

Often this is tidier than `Aggregate` as it does not require all the Anonymous function syntax. It also has the advantage of only putting a separator between input strings. With aggregate you often have to trim the result.

Comment: `String.Join` does not work as it was mentioned in question... But maybe you view it different way - in that case please put an example here.

Comment: are you passing it a string or char as the seperator?

Comment: one character so for this case any of them is fine

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Finally I have figured out the answer using `String.Join()`, but what changed since the time when I posted the question: no errors are now apperaing in the runtime.

Comment: I am really sorry but I have tried `String.Join` yet before posting to StackOverflow. As you can see in the question, it built fine, but crashed during the runtime. Adding `ToArray()` was the missing piece in this case, not `String.Join`. In a post before I thanked you for effort, not for solution, because simply applying `String.Join` throws an exception what I already known before. You can see this in second part of the question. From your first comment in your answer (are you passing...) I got hope you will post some working example here... But finally finding answer was left on me.